# GCP cloud function nodejs upload as zip for deployment failed with error Build failed: function.js does not exist;

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have tried gen 1 and gen 2 for uploading zip folder with index.js and some png files to be used in the cloud function.

When I upload the zip to the cloud storage it gives error :Build failed: function.js does not exist

I am not sure what I am missing. Tried adding main file in package.json, renaming file to the entry point of the function

Please share if there is any folder structure that I need to follow or something special in package.json.

Thanks in advance !!

Added more information:

I have followed https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#directory-structure and https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions

And getting: [image]

Comment: Have you uploaded your cloud functions zip to cloud storage. Then while creating a new function just provide the path of that zip at the 2nd step of creating a cloud function where you will find an option with `source code` : Select `ZIP from cloud storage`. Then deploy. For more details also check [**Deploy from Cloud Storage**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy#from-cloud-storage)

Comment: Didn't work. it gives the same error

Comment: I am following exactly this directory structure and sample: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#directory-structure and
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions

Comment: If you have the functions zip in GCS. You can create a new function by providing the source code as that zip code. Can you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the problem was fixed when I compressed the single files in stead of the folder itself. When you compress the folder, a zip is created with the folder inside of it. Google Cloud only reads the folder from the zip, and not the files within there, which makes it unable to find the main function.